# Go to HTML page from PHP function

Tags: php, html, mysql

I started PHP recently and I was wondering : 
 I have a php file which only contains a function called `sqlConnect();` which checks that the user isn't yet logged into the MySQL DB, and if so, redirects the user to an html page which is a form for the user to enter the username and password for the DB. 
 After the user has submitted the form, I want to get back to the point where I left (in the function). 
One thing you should know too is that the `$_SESSION` is started in another file which calls this function. 
 
Here's what I tried, yet it didn't work : 
connect.php :

```
<?php
  function sqlConnect() {
    $_SESSION['CurrentPage'] = "/php/sql/connect.php";
    if(!array_key_exists('mysql_username', $_SESSION) && !array_key_exists('mysql_passwd', $_SESSION)) {
      echo "<script>window.location='/forms/sql_login.php';</script>";
    }
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username   = $_SESSION['mysql_username'];
    $passwd     = $_SESSION['mysql_passwd'];
    $db_name    = "ToolDB";
    // create connection
    $sql_connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $passwd, $db_name);
    // check that it was established
    if($sql_connection->connect_error) {
      $msg = $sql_connection->connect_error;
      echo "<script>alert('Impossible de se connecter à la base de données MySQL : $msg.');</script>";
      return NULL;
    }
    else {
      $_SESSION['mysql_username'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['mysql_passwd']   = $passwd;
      return $sql_connection;
    }
  }
?>
```

sql_connection.php :

```
<?php session_start(); $url = $_SESSION['CurrentPage']; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Team Schedule Making Tool (form)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <h2 style="margin-left: 10px; font-family: sans-serif;">Team Schedule Making Tool (MySQL Login Page)</h2>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="bodyElement">
        <form action="<?php echo $url ?>" method="post">
            <p>Nom d'utilisateur : <input type="text" name="mysql_username" /></p>
            <p>Mot de passe : <input type="password" name="mysql_passwd"/></p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
        </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anybody know how to achieve that ?

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
ob_end_clean();
header("Location: example.com");
exit();
```

Put this at the end where you want the user to be redirected.
Header() doesn't let you redirect after an output is given, but
     `ob_end_clean()`
allows you to redirect after an output.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm new to PHP and I read that if you have an echo you need that to be able to redirect, but I'll edit that out because I trust your opinion more than mine

Comment: You're right! I missed the echo's in the OP's code. In addition it looks like the OP is trying to use JavaScript redirects.

Comment: So he does need the ob_end_clean()? Again you probably know more than me

Comment: Yes, he does need that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function to redirect clients to another page.

```
<?php
    header('Location: <your page>');
    exit;
?>
```